# Async wait for event in same event c#

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

suppose I have event which show me that page is fully loaded.

```
private void browser_IsLoading(object sender, endEventArgs e)
if (e.Loading == false){ //Browser is not loading
    foo();
}
```

But page is sometimes not fully loaded, so this event is not completely reliable. But in this unreliable status same event occurs right after,  but only with e.Loading = true.

I would like to wait for some time lets say 2 secs and then continue with foo(), but only if another event IsLoading with e.Loading == true is not executed during that 2 secs.

So basically foo() should be only executed if browser says that it is not loading and then at least for 2 secs no e.Loading = true event occurs

How can this be done in .net ?

Petr

Comment: I think your description is very vague and you don't understand asp.net page life cycle. Please read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: That's not asp .net, it's a winforms with a WebBrowser for what I see...

Comment: Why not use a more appropriate event like [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah I would use the DocumentCompleted listed above.  To address the question as its asked I would use Task.Delay() to perform a wait that doesn't block the current thread.